# Dynamically Loading a C++ class via Python capsules

Tags: python, c++, pointer-to-member, dynamic-loading, python-c-extension

This question is mostly academic.
It stems from some design questions I came across while working on wrappers for an existing C++ project.

When working with C/C++ extensions for Python, it is possible to dynamically load C-level functions that were wrapped in Python capsule objects in other extension modules (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#providing-a-c-api-for-an-extension-module)).
This means that, if you want to work with a C++ class wrapped in another module you have these two options (at least):

- Link against the original C++ library and include the corresponding headers, and only use capsules to load functions that aren't in the original library (e.g. conversions between Python and C++ types).
- Expose a C-like API by writing a factory functions that mimic the constructors and then wrapping the methods inside functions that take a pointer to an instance of the class as additional argument.

My question is this: **Is there any way to share C++ classes between Python extension modules that allows the classes to be used in an idiomatic way (i.e. as they would be used in C++) while also loading them dynamically from another Python extension module?**

The only possible way I can think of would be re-declaring the class with the needed method signatures under an anonymous namespace (to keep the names private to each module) and then defining the methods to wrap pointers to member functions that were loaded via capsules. Is that even possible?